# Metro - Detecting if Location Services is enabled

Tags: c#, geolocation, microsoft-metro

I am building a C# Metro application and I need to determine if Location Services is enabled at the device level and at the app level (via Settings charm -> Permissions -> Location) in my application.  How can I go about getting this information?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check Property LocationStatus of Geolocator

```
Geolocator geo=new Geolocator();
if(PositionStatus.Disabled.Equals(geo.LocationStatus))
    //geolocalization disabled
```

LocationStatus will be disabled if user opt out from geolocalization and if the device doesn't have geolocalization sensors